# How to turn off Applescript guessing of Application name?

Tags: applescript, after-effects

I am trying to target the application named "Adobe After Effects CC 2014" with applescript by using this code:

```
tell application "Adobe After Effects CC 2014"
    activate
end tell
```

The thing is, I also have an application named "Adobe After Effects CC 2015" installed. If 2015 is not running there's no problem, the applescript behaves as it should (starts 2014 if it isn't running or brings it to the front if it is). But when 2015 is running, the script, when ran from the Script Editor automatically corrects "Adobe After Effects CC 2014" to "Adobe After Effects CC 2015" and runs it through 2015.

Is there a way to turn off this behaviour of automatically correcting the version number?

I know a solution could be to shut down 2015 before running the script, but in this situation I need it to keep running as well. I am on OS X 10.10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can target the application using the full path according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW9). So it would be

```
tell application "/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC 2014/Adobe After Effects CC 2014.app"
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a creator-code problem (to use the old-school terminology). I believe that the applescript, once compiled, will use the bundle identifier of the application and the problem is that the bundle identifier is probably the same for both versions of the program.

You might want to try to right-mouse the 2014 version and open contents. Then open the Contents folder, and in there you will see Info.plist. Make a copy of this file and edit it to change the Bundle identifier field and add a 2014 to the end of the identifier (probably something like com.adobe...2014.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tell application "Adobe After Effects CC 2014" 
if application "Adobe After Effects CC 2015"
tell application "Adobe After Effects CC 2015"
close
tell application "Adobe After Effects CC 2014" 
    activate
end tell
```